# Eliminating recursive SQL Duplicates

Tags: sql, db2, duplicates, recursive-query

I'm having issues with my script bringing back duplicate names and I'm not sure how to fix it. My script concatenates columns into a row. Basically I have admin names that I need listed in the same row and column of the building they are assigned. The admin names are listed multiple times and when I concatenate the rows it lists the admin name as follows (John Doe | John Doe). Point of Contact and list sometimes contain different names. I need to exclude the duplicate names in the list. I have attached a screen shot of the current and desired results. Using a db2 database but not sure of the version.  Your help is appreciated.

```
       WITH
    /*****************************************************
    *** The cte was used to generate test data easily. ***
    *****************************************************/
    sample_data
( rownum, project_id , project_name ,  name_last , name_first, point_of_contact, building_id, building_name, hours_used,
hours_to_use, percentage_used, capability, bucket_a, bucket_b, bucket_c  ) AS
(
VALUES
  (1, 10 , 'ELITE', 'Gamb', 'Susan', 'Susan Gamb | Amber Jones', 2, 'Main' , 80, 0, 1.0, 6000, 12000, 9600, 5100)
, (2, 10 , 'ELITE', 'Gamb', 'Susan', 'Susan Gamb | Amber Jones', 2 , 'Main', 80,  0, 1.0, 7000, 12500, 8000, 4000)
, (3, 10 , 'ELITE', 'Jones', 'Amber', 'Susan Gamb | Amber Jones', 2, 'Main', 80, 0, 1.0, 6000, 12000, 9600, 5100)
, (4, 10 , 'ELITE', 'Jones', 'Amber', 'Susan Gamb | Amber Jones', 2, 'Main', 80, 0, 1.0, 7000, 12500, 8000, 4000)
, (1, 10 , 'ELITE', 'Gamb', 'Susan', 'Susan Gamb | Amber Jones', 6 ,'Warehouse', 40, 40, .5, 6000, 12500, 9600, 5100)
, (2, 10 , 'ELITE', 'Gamb', 'Susan', 'Susan Gamb | Amber Jones', 6, 'Warehouse' , 40, 40, .5, 7000, 12000, 8000, 4000)
, (3, 10 , 'ELITE', 'Jones', 'Amber',  'Susan Gamb | Amber Jones', 6, 'Warehouse' , 40, 40, .5, 6000, 12500, 9600, 5100)
, (4, 10 , 'ELITE', 'Jones', 'Amber',  'Susan Gamb | Amber Jones', 6, 'Warehouse' , 40, 40, .5, 6000, 12000, 8000, 4000 )
, (1, 1040 , 'ROADRUNNER', 'Sugar', 'Paul', 'Paul Sugar | Rob Brown', 2 , 'Main', 60,  20, .75, 5000, 1000, 1200, 4100 )
, (2, 1040 , 'ROADRUNNER', 'Sugar', 'Paul', 'Paul Sugar | Rob Brown', 2, 'Main',  60, 20, .75, 4000, 1500, 1000, 3000)
, (3, 1040 , 'ROADRUNNER', 'Brown', 'Rob', 'Paul Sugar | Rob Brown', 2, 'Main', 60, 20, .75, 4500, 2000, 1200, 4100)
, (4, 1040 , 'ROADRUNNER', 'Brown', 'Rob', 'Paul Sugar | Rob Brown', 2, 'Main', 60, 20, .75, 4000, 1500, 1000, 3000)
, (1, 1040 , 'ROADRUNNER', 'Sugar', 'Paul', 'Paul Sugar | Rob Brown',  6 , 'Warehouse', 60, 20, .75, 4500, 2000, 1200, 4100)
, (2, 1040 , 'ROADRUNNER', 'Sugar', 'Paul', 'Paul Sugar | Rob Brown',  6, 'Warehouse', 60, 20, .75, 4000, 1500, 1000, 3000)
, (2, 1040 , 'ROADRUNNER',  'Brown', 'Rob', 'Paul Sugar | Rob Brown',  6, 'Warehouse', 60, 20, .75, 4500, 2000, 1200, 4100 )
, (3, 1040 , 'ROADRUNNER',  'Brown', 'Rob', 'Paul Sugar | Rob Brown',  6, 'Warehouse', 60, 20, .75, 4000, 1500, 1000, 3000)

)
    ,

           t2(PROJECT_ID, LIST, POINT_OF_CONTACT, PROJECT_NAME, BUILDING_ID, BUILDING_NAME, HOURS_USED, HOURS_TO_USE, PERCENTAGE_USED, CAPABILITY,
           BUCKET_A, BUCKET_B, BUCKET_C, cnt) AS
        ( SELECT    PROJECT_ID,
                    VARCHAR(NAME_FIRST CONCAT ' ' CONCAT NAME_LAST, 6000),
                    POINT_OF_CONTACT,
                    PROJECT_NAME,
                    BUILDING_ID,
                    BUILDING_NAME,
                    HOURS_USED,
                    HOURS_TO_USE,
                    PERCENTAGE_USED,
                    CAPABILITY,
                    BUCKET_A,
                    BUCKET_B,
                    BUCKET_C,
                    1
        FROM SAMPLE_DATA
                WHERE rowNum = 1
                UNION ALL
        SELECT
            t2.PROJECT_ID,
                    t2.list || ' | ' || SAMPLE_DATA.NAME_FIRST CONCAT ' ' CONCAT SAMPLE_DATA.NAME_LAST,
                    SAMPLE_DATA.POINT_OF_CONTACT,
                    SAMPLE_DATA.PROJECT_NAME,
                    SAMPLE_DATA.BUILDING_ID,
                    SAMPLE_DATA.BUILDING_NAME,
                    SAMPLE_DATA.HOURS_USED,
                    SAMPLE_DATA.HOURS_TO_USE,
                    SAMPLE_DATA.PERCENTAGE_USED,
                    SAMPLE_DATA.CAPABILITY,
                    SAMPLE_DATA.BUCKET_A,
                    SAMPLE_DATA.BUCKET_B,
                    SAMPLE_DATA.BUCKET_C,
                    t2.cnt + 1
        FROM t2, SAMPLE_DATA

                WHERE t2.PROJECT_ID = SAMPLE_DATA.PROJECT_ID
                AND          t2.BUILDING_ID = SAMPLE_DATA.BUILDING_ID
                AND   t2.cnt + 1 = SAMPLE_DATA.rowNum
                 )    
        SELECT
                   PROJECT_ID,
                   PROJECT_NAME,
                   POINT_OF_CONTACT,
                   BUILDING_ID,
                   BUILDING_NAME,
                   HOURS_USED,
                   HOURS_TO_USE,
                   PERCENTAGE_USED,
                   CAPABILITY,
                   BUCKET_A,
                   BUCKET_B,
                   BUCKET_C,
                   list
        FROM t2
                WHERE ( PROJECT_ID, BUILDING_ID, cnt ) IN (
        SELECT PROJECT_ID, BUILDING_ID, MAX(rowNum)
        FROM SAMPLE_DATA
                GROUP BY PROJECT_ID, BUILDING_ID )    
                order by PROJECT_NAME
```

Desired Results:
[image]

Comment: can you include some sample data in SQL Fiddle?  That will allow us to test any modifications we make.

Comment: SQL Fiddle does not offer db2

Comment: Ah.  That will make this harder.  You will just need to try a DISTINCT or GROUP BY to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: I added my current results into SQL Fiddle but it is SQL Server 2008.  I'm using DB2.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0899/1/0

Comment: I'm not sure that will solve my issue

Comment: Right now you just included the results table, not the source data so I can actually test the query.  You are rolling up the names so obviously what needs to be done is make them unique, how and where to do that without affecting the rest of the query is the tricky bit.

Comment: I edited my question to include the source data that I'm working with from the base query.  I hope this helps clarify things.  Really looking for a resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to test your query in MSSQL server and got it working.  I did my best to look up the equivalent functions in db2.  Even if this doesn't work straight out, I hope it puts you on the right path.

In your second select for t2, I changed:

```
t2.list || ' | ' || SAMPLE_DATA.NAME_FIRST CONCAT ' ' CONCAT SAMPLE_DATA.NAME_LAST,
```

to

```
        WHEN LOCATE(SAMPLE_DATA.NAME_FIRST CONCAT ' ' CONCAT SAMPLE_DATA.NAME_LAST, t2.list) > 0 THEN t2.list
        ELSE t2.list || ' | ' || SAMPLE_DATA.NAME_FIRST || ' ' || SAMPLE_DATA.NAME_LAST
        END,
```

Basically, we are checking if that person is already in the list, if they are, return the current list, if they aren't, add them to the list.

Comment: Much appreciated Vulcronus.  Exactly what I needed.